# Extensión Code Runner en VSC

Tags: c++, json, c, visual-studio, extensiones

Estoy programando con C/C++ en Visual Studio Code y pretendo que me aparezca lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tal como se ve en la imagen es así como debería aparecerme al usar esa extensión.

Averiguando he llegado a la conclusión que es una función de la extensión "Code Runner" y que configurando de la siguiente manera en el archivo: settings.json :

```
"code-runner.showExecutionMessage": true
```

haría que apretando el signito play(Run Code) o Ctrl+Alt+N el código compile, se ejecute y me aparezca lo que quiero pero no es así.
Por eso le pregunto a esta comunidad si alguien sabe como podría obtener los resultados de la primer foto considerando la ultima, desde ya muchas gracias y disculpen las molestias.

Ultima foto, lo que a mi me aparece:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto la página donde habla de la configuración del Code Runner por la dudas:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner

Y a continuación como tengo configurado el settings.json:

```
{
    "code-runner.defaultLanguage": "c++",
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": true,
    "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": true                                                           
}
```

Comment: Lo que se muestra en la primera imagen es en la sección de output, tu estas en la terminal, creo que eso podría hacer la diferencia de la vista.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón denso !! Pero sabes como hacer para que se me ejecute en el **Output** y no en la **Terminal** ???

Answer (score 1):

ya resolví todo lo que quería, gracias a tu observación de que el código se me estaba ejecutando en la **Terminal** y no en el **Output**.

Entonces para resolverlo es tan sencillo como cambiar   `"code-runner.runInTerminal": false,` quedándome la configuración siguiente:

```
    "code-runner.defaultLanguage": "c++",
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": false,
    "code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": true,
    "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": true,
    "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Disabled"
```

Con esa configuración se me soluciono el problema, muchas gracias!!